# Is there a browser that shows javascript modified html as text

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I'm using `jQuery` to dynamically create some content on a web page.  I'm using `Firefox` to test.  I am able to view the modified `html` (i.e. the html as it appears after the `$(document).ready` function has completed) by using the inspector debugging tool but this tool shows the information as a tree so I can't cut and paste it as text.  Using the "view page source" option shows the `html`, however it shows the original `html`, not the final modified `html`.  Is there a browser (or a browser tool) that will show the modified `html` as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox (or any other modern browser), in that live DOM tree view you mentioned ("Elements"), you can right-click elements and copy them (as text) to the clipboard.

On Firefox for Windows it's right-click and then choose either Copy Inner HTML or Copy Outer HTML. (Oddly, in Firefox for Linux, it's right-click, Copy, and then there's a submenu with Inner HTML and Outer HTML on it.) (It's similar on other browsers.)

If you want to do some edits in a text editor and paste them into the live page, there are also paste options; or there's an edit option to do it right there in the Elements panel (though that's only useful for very small edits).

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all of the additional details.  Very helpful!